# Lookup value on cell with comma separated data

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel worksheet with 2 columns. Cell A has values like

```
Column A
111,222-225, 333
010, 011,444-499
```

1. How can we lookup a value on this column, say 333 and output corresponding value on adjacent column --(in column B or C etc similar to Vlookup)?

Tried Vlookup & doesn't seem to be a good choice as the first column value needs to be unique not comma separated.

2. How could we tackle the same above scenario if the lookup value is in a range (say 224, which is in the range of 222-225)?

Thanks in advance for the assistance -

Comment: That style of storing data is compact, and humans can scan it and figure it out.  But it's nearly useless for doing any kind of direct lookup or extraction by Excel.  It suffers from multiple problems: multiple values in a cell, ranges in a cell, ranges mixed with values, non-uniform delimiters, etc.  It can be done using seriously convoluted formulas or VBA, but you're talking about a mini-application to interface with the data.  If you want to be able to use Excel to do lookups or extractions, you need to store the values in (or convert them to) a form that Excel can directly deal with.

Answer (score 0):

VLookup starts finding from the very first letter of a sorted list. It cannot find valued in the middle of cells, so it will not work.

1. say you have your string to be searched in cell C1, then

   "*"&C1&"*"

construct will let you search with the use of wild strings.

say, Enter this formula in B1

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&C1&"*"))
```

It will give you count of cells that have number that your have searched. But it will not extract or show number. So, with this method you can search and then extract your data.

2. if a number lies between a range say 223 lying between 222-225, there is no direct formula to search that.

A formula can be constructed that separates first value and second value of the range   (identified by two numbers separated by -) and then determines if your searched number can be between them.

Comment: Even using wildcards is complex because the target might be contained inside a different value having more characters; and you can't simply include the delimiters because the first, middle, and last values are delimited differently, not to mention the ranges.